# variable is not getting value from input hidden with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I'm trying to get the input value but the result its blank. Can you help me?

```
**HTML:**
<input type="text" id="totalscore2" ng-model="10">


**JavaScript:**
angular.module('teB', [])
 .controller('teBB', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  let total = document.getElementById("totalscore2").value
  console.log(total)
  const options = {
    series: [total],
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: 'radialBar',
    },
    plotOptions: {
      radialBar: {
        hollow: {
          size: '70%',
        }
      },
    },
    labels: ['Puntuación'],
  }

  let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#charttest"), options)
  chart.render()
  

 }]);
```

I want to get the ng-model value to then show it in a chart

Comment: I want to get the value of the input totalscore2 and store inside the total variable. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `document.getElementById('totalscore2').getAtrribute('ng-model')`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to write tag element like:

Here whatever the value in input field, "TotalScore" is the the scope variable which can be access in controller by
$scope.TotalScope.